# Mockito 2 for Android Instrumentation test : Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, android-espresso, byte-buddy

I'm using Mockito 2 and Espresso for Unit tests, and met a problem trying to use Mockito 2 in Instrumentation test. While running the test, I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:74)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
at $Proxy5.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:232)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:226)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:64)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1864)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1777)
at com.armop.insight.views.activity.InsightActivityTest.testUserResultReturnsEmpty(InsightActivityTest.kt:66)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:369)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2075)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration@5ea25e5
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:54)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:57)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:44)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:21)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:18)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getMockMaker(Plugins.java:34)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:24)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException:
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker. (This mock maker is not supported on Android.)


IMPORTANT INFORMATION FOR ANDROID USERS:

The regular Byte Buddy mock makers cannot generate code on an Android VM!
To resolve this, please use the 'mockito-android' dependency for your application:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22mockito-android%22%20g%3A%22org.mockito%22

Java               : 0.9
JVM vendor name    : The Android Project
JVM vendor version : 2.1.0
JVM name           : Dalvik
JVM version        : 0.9
JVM info           : null
OS name            : Linux
OS version         : 3.18.91+

at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:171)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:49)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$ProcessProvider$ForCurrentVm$ForLegacyVm.resolve(ByteBuddyAgent.java:940)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$ProcessProvider$ForCurrentVm.resolve(ByteBuddyAgent.java:925)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:352)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:320)
at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:306)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:101)
... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.armop.debug.test-GWx-9OMGi9FTj01c1acroQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.armop.debug-28ywc-fJ-zzWAgMPBESlGQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.armop.debug.test-GWx-9OMGi9FTj01c1acroQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.armop.debug-28ywc-fJ-zzWAgMPBESlGQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.armop.debug.test-GWx-9OMGi9FTj01c1acroQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.armop.debug-28ywc-fJ-zzWAgMPBESlGQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 52 more
```

And here is the test code.

```
 @Test
fun testUserResultReturnsEmpty() {

    val userMock = Mockito.mock(UserModel::class.java)
    Mockito.`when`(ArmOpApplication.getUserFromPrefs()).thenReturn(userMock)

    mActivityRule.launchActivity(Intent())
    mCountDownLatch.await(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

    assertNotNull(mActivityRule.activity.mInsightCategories)

    assertNull(mActivityRule.activity.mData)
    assertNull(mActivityRule.activity.insightsRecyclerView.adapter)
}
```

I've googled for more information and found out, that I need to use mockito-android instead of mockito core, and added those lines in application's build.gradle file

```
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:${libMockitoAndroidVersion}"
androidTestImplementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.2.0'

where libMockitoAndroidVersion = 2.16.0
```

Also, I've added org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker file into the androidTest resource directory to work with Kotlin's classes.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is dexmaker necessary here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace it seems like you are using the inline Byte Buddy mock maker which does not work on Android. Make sure that you have not included it transitively somehow as both plugins being available would load the one that is added to the class path first.

Comment: How can we check whether we included transitively?

Comment: Check your build tool for a dependency graph.

Comment: In Bazel in this case.

Comment: mockito-android itself brings net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android which in turn brings net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy!

Answer (score 9):

Working with Android replace

```
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockito_core_version"
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockito_core_version"
```

for

```
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$mockito_core_version"
```

My version was: `$mockito_core_version = '2.28.2'`

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue and none of the solutions here worked for me. My problem was that I was mixing both mockito libraries

```
//BAD CODE
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0"
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:3.3.3"


//GOOD CODE - just use one
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0"
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've got similar problem. I my case that was invalid declaration in `resource/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file. During some refactoring process IDE replaced correct value:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

with this one:

```
infrastructure-maker-inline
```

I've noticed that accidental change while reviewing the commit diff because it didn't look suspicious for first look.

Comment: What is mock-maker?

Answer (score 2):

This helped me

```
androidTestImplementation("org.koin:koin-test:1.0.2")
{ exclude("org.mockito", "mockito-inline") }
androidTestImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5")
```

Koin represents some library that contain org.mockito

Comment: Thank you, I could not figure out where the error was coming from, even when I used the `mockito-android` lib.

Comment: Koin is related to OP's issue?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I didn't use Koin in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the stacktrace I found this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration
```

Enlighted by this issue([#824 Exception when using mock-maker-inline](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/824)), I resolved the same problem by adding tools.jar to my classpath in intellij

[add tools.jar to classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORTB5.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my case it worked with adding mockito kotlin dependency and i think it would be better to stay away from inline library, because as i read somewhere it is just a dependency to check final class mocking issue solution and later it will be stopped of updating

use these 2 dependencies

testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0'

testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0"